# показ определенных данных из бд

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

В базе (таблица - posts)  есть статья, в колонке category назначена категория technologies/new

если статья с категорией - technologies/new то на сайте нужно показывать юзеру 2 кнопки

```
<a> Открыть </a>    
<a> Удалить </a>
```

а если статья с другой категорией то нужно показывать 3 кнопки

```
<a> Открыть </a>    
<a> Удалить </a>
<a> Править </a>
```

Вопрос как правильно прописать условие вывода

```
<? if (---?????????---- ) { ?>    

  <? }else{ ?>    

<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Делаете подключение к БД, затем с помощью sql и php делаете вывод, например:

*

```
$host="localhost";
$user="toor";
$pass="12345"; //установленный вами пароль
$db_name="database";

$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
mysql_query('SET NAMES `utf8`');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM `posts` ORDER BY name ASC", $link);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo '<h1>'.$result['title'].';
    echo "</div>";

}
```

*

в данном случае из базы "database", таблицы `posts` выводится параметр title

Answer (score 0):

Судя по уточнению, вам просто в базе данных нужно создать ячейку в которой будет храниться категория, а потом когда вы будете выводить кнопки, берите данные из БД и проверяйте та категория что вам нужна или нет, пример.

```
<?php
$data = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `posts`", $connect);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    if($result['category'] == ' technologies/new') {
    ?>
        <a> Открыть </a>    
        <a> Удалить </a>    
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <a> Открыть </a>    
        <a> Удалить </a>
        <a> Править </a>
    <?php
}
?>
```